# Novice GridBagLayout Issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

Breaking my old habits, I have created a GUI using GridBagLayout.  I am still very new to this container, so obviously there will be flaws with my code.

When I run the program, the GUI looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh1GG.png

Not too bad for a first try, but the window height is bigger than I expected!  I added scroll panes to the separate panels so that I could make the application smaller.  Because I didn't set a limit on window size, I think the scrollbars aren't showing because Java automatically sizes the window so that as many of the components show as possible.

Also, the bottom label "0 out of.." is sort of offset to the right.  No big deal.

But the real horror shows when I resize the window.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/58EJ3.png

Now we get the scrollbars, but the bottom panel suddenly grows huge and the other three panels get all strange.  (the horizontal scrollbars aren't even supposed to show)

Here is my code.  Thanks to all the GUI experts out there that can offer any help!!

```
...create the components blah blah blah
//----------------------- ADD COMPONENTS TO PANELS -----------------------

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0.5;
    c.ipadx = 3;
    c.ipady = 3;

    //TODO: Add "Level", "Amount", etc. labels

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    //Normal troops
    {
        c.gridy = i;

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        normalTroopPanel.add(icon[i], c);

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 1;
        normalTroopPanel.add(setLevel[i], c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        normalTroopPanel.add(setAmount[i], c);

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 20, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 3;
        normalTroopPanel.add(typeTotalCost[i], c);

        c.gridx = 4;
        normalTroopPanel.add(typeTotalTime[i], c);
    }
    normalTroopPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 520));

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; i++)   //Dark troops
    {
        c.gridy = i;

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        darkTroopPanel.add(icon[i], c);

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 1;
        darkTroopPanel.add(setLevel[i], c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        darkTroopPanel.add(setAmount[i], c);

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 20, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 3;
        darkTroopPanel.add(typeTotalCost[i], c);

        c.gridx = 4;
        darkTroopPanel.add(typeTotalTime[i], c);
    }
    darkTroopPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));

    for (int i = 15; i < 20; i++)   //Spells
    {
        c.gridy = i;

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        spellPanel.add(icon[i], c);

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 1;
        spellPanel.add(setLevel[i], c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        spellPanel.add(setAmount[i], c);

        c.insets = new Insets(10, 20, 10, 0);
        c.gridx = 3;
        spellPanel.add(typeTotalCost[i], c);

        c.gridx = 4;
        spellPanel.add(typeTotalTime[i], c);
    }
    spellPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));

    //Totals panel
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    totalsPanel.add(spaceTaken, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    totalsPanel.add(setHousingLimit, c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    totalsPanel.add(totalElixirCost, c);
    c.gridx = 3;
    totalsPanel.add(totalDarkCost, c);
    c.gridx = 4;
    totalsPanel.add(totalTime, c);

    //Add scrollbars to our troop/spell panels so they can all fit in a reasonable window
    JScrollPane normalTroopScroll = new JScrollPane(normalTroopPanel);
    JScrollPane darkTroopScroll = new JScrollPane(darkTroopPanel);
    JScrollPane spellScroll = new JScrollPane(spellPanel);

    //Bundle it all up!
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight = 2;
    armyEntryPanel.add(normalTroopScroll, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    armyEntryPanel.add(darkTroopScroll, c);
    c.gridy = 1;
    armyEntryPanel.add(spellScroll, c);
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    armyEntryPanel.add(totalsPanel, c);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The combination of `fill` and `weighty` is causing the main problems.

Try setting the `weighty` to `1` for the components at the top (scroll pane) and `weighty` to `0` for the components at the bottom. You may consider setting the fill to `NONE` as well (for the bottom components)

Essentially, you never reset the constraints

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Now, the bottom panel doesn't resize (yay), but now this happens when I try to make the window smaller:

http://i.imgur.com/weedAeb.png

Comment: I should add that I put c.weighty = 0 right after the "Totals Panel" comment.

Comment: One GridBagLayout gets to a point that it can't honour the preferredSize, it reverts to using the components minimum size. Consider using weighty 1 for the other components

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you give your bottom colorful panels a `preferredDimension` based on the screen resolution, the font size, etc. That way, it *may* stay the way you want it to stay.

Also, try setting the `Insets` for these components, see if that helps.

Comment: I was told not to use that when using GridBagLayout.  Could the odd size have something to do with c.weighty?

Comment: @ScottSinischo I am having a look at it. Making an SSCCE. Let me see :)